# Qlikview - Passing variable as value in Nested-Set-Analysis

Tags: reporting, analytics, business-intelligence, dashboard, qlikview

I am trying to achieve a complex set analysis in Qlikview.

**Aim:** To fetch the second highest sales of an outlet for a particular product where the ranking is done on the complete set excluding the currently selected outlet ({Super Set} - {Current Selection}).

**Challenge:** The ranking needs to be done on the latest quarter and not on the aggregation of all and I am trying to pass the quarter value via a variable. Since the position where the variable is to be passed as value is in the second depth within the set analysis, the code fails.

**Code:**

```
=SUM(
    {1<[Product Brand]={'Product1'},
       [Outlet]=
           {"=RANK(SUM({<[Product Brand]={'Product1'},
                         [Outlet]=e([Outlet]),
                         [Quarter]={"$(=$(AccMaxQuarter))"}
                        >}
      [Sales]))=1"}
      >}
  [Sales])
```

**where:**
*AccMaxQuarter* : The variable containing the latest quarter

If I replace the variable with hard-coded constant, it works. The variable itself is correctly initialized and contains the accurate value.

Comment: Why do you need this {"$(=$(AccMaxQuarter))"} rather than {'$(AccMaxQuarter)'}  ?

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. Thanks a lot. The reason I was using that syntax was because I read it on a post here on StackOverFlow.